# Android kernel source compile error

Tags: kernel

When I run command

```
make -j3
```

I get this error:

> net/netfilter/xt_mark.c:16:37: fatal error: linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h:
>   No such file or directory

How to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Error

```
fatal error: linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h: No such file or directory
```

normally arises when you build kernel on *shared folders* or other filesystem which doesn't support links.

Build kernel on local Linux filesystem (ext4, xfs, etc.).

Comment: I already have transfered source from SHARED folder on my home folder.

Comment: If you unpack(untar) sources into **shared** folder, you already have given file missed. You need to unpack sources directly to your home folder.